# How to use stutrek/scrollMonitor's method 'one'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, viewport

I'm using this code to trigger animation when it is in viewport:

```
    var myElement = document.getElementById("first-text");
    var elementWatcher = scrollMonitor.create(myElement);

    elementWatcher.enterViewport(function() {
            console.log( 'I have entered the viewport' );
            var text = anime({
                    targets: '#first-text',
                    translateX: -600,
                    opacity: 0,
                    direction: 'reverse',
                    easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
            });
    });
    elementWatcher.exitViewport(function() {
            console.log( 'I have left the viewport' );
    });
```

This make animation trigger everytime after element gets in viewport.
How to make it to trigger just once after page is loaded?

Comment: Just a suggestion. Why not just create a variable which contains boolean flag before entering the function.

Comment: Cause scrollMonitor has that method, elementWatcher.on/off/one, and I just want to know how to use it in this code. And have in mind that I'm noob at this, so I need good description how to do something. :) https://github.com/stutrek/scrollMonitor

Comment: Ohhh you're using an external plugin. Sorry about that

Comment: Yea. Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry bro. Not familiar with it. Someone will help maybe

Comment: @RobiZzT Have you solved the problem? Check if my answer helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not clear about the elementWatcher.on/off/one but as a workaround, do this

```
elementWatcher.exitViewport(function() {
   console.log( 'I have left the viewport' );
   elementWatcher.destroy(); // stops future watcher 
});
```

Comment: Yea, I have been using it that way, and it works as I want it to work. Thank you for help.